# Finite sets mapped to another set....is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am looking at my lecture notes which introduces the notion of compactness in *topological* spaces. Now, it starts with trying to investigate the question "what are the assumptions needed about to topological space $X$ in order to prove that every continuous map $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded?"

Then, it says

> Observe that if $X$ is finite, then any function $f: X \to \mathbb{X}$ continuous **or not** is bounded since we can take $M=max_{x \in X}|f(x)|$ where $M$ is well-defined as $X$ is finite.

I don't understand this. Consider $X=\{0,1\}$ or well, if one wishes, $X=\{0, 0.5,1\}$. What if I define a map $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$?
$X$ is finite, yes? It has finite number of elements, in the above, either $2$ o $3$ elements in the set.

Well, clearly, $f(0) \to \infty$. And $0 \in X$. It says the map doesn't have to be continuous(it can be too, so it doesn't matter) so I have a finite $X$ and a function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ that is **not** bounded (we have a map to a non well-defined number, $\infty$).

Well, I think I have found a counter example to this statement. What's wrong with my reasoning? What have I missed?

Comment: How are you defining $f(0)$ in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking that a function should be given by a formula, which is not necessarily the case. In your example, $f(0)$ is not defined, and limits make no sense because the space is discrete: when $x\ne0$, the values of $f$ do not "approach anything", they are just $f(1)=1$ and $f(1/2)=2$. In any case, to have a function $f:X\to \mathbb R$, it should be defined for all elements, so you should say what $f(0)$ is. As soon as you do, you have at most three possible values, so $f$ has a maximum.

Comment: Understood, yes, that makes sense; infinity can only be approached as a concept but not as a defined number. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"$f:X\to \mathbb R$ is a function" implies that $f(x)$ is defined for each $x\in X$ ($X$ is the domain of $f$).

You do not have a counterexample because $0$ is in your set $X$, but your $f$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not defined at $0$; $\frac{1}{0}=r\in\mathbb R$ would imply $1=0\cdot r=0$, which is absurd.